# Catching all errors

Tags: c++, exception

In my program I want to catch every error in a function. I've tried using a try/catch but the program still exits. I've set up an example of what I want to catch

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<string> test;
    test.push("lel");
    try {
        test.pop();
        test.pop();
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "Caught" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This still causes the program to exit. How can I catch any error, or if it's not possible, this specific error?

Comment: Catching means that the exception will be processed by the innermost handling block, doesn't mean your program will never restore execution (unless the OS handles the exception and decides so)

Comment: @Rakibul's answer describes why this doesn't work.  Instead, you can either check before every `pop()` for an empty container, or use a different container type that does `throw` an exception if you try to `pop` while empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stack::pop()` does not throw any `exception` when the stack is empty. Rather it is **undefined behavior** to pop from an empty stack. Since no exception is thrown, your `catch` clause can not *catch* anything, rather program terminates ( anything can happen in **UB**).

So about your intention of *catching all error*, I think it is good practice to put a `try-catch` in `main`to catch anything that escaped from any other place, and you should be able to catch if *exception is actually being thrown*. Just take care of some issues:

1. Control may not reach in your `catch` block in case of any **UB**.
2. C++ can not handle more than one exceptions simultaneously, in that case program will most likely terminate in place where it happens (specially be careful so that exception does not leave any destructor).
3. Throwing exception that is not in exception specification list of a function (most likely program will terminate).

Comment: I agree, that's why the catch clause is not being executed. +1

Answer (score 1):

The `std::stack::pop` function is defined by C11++ §23.6.5.2 as

```
void pop() { c.pop_back(); }
```

Table 101 in C++11 §23.2.3/16 places the following requirement on a call to `pop_pack`:

> **”** *Requires:* `a.empty()` shall be `false`.

This means that the call to `pop` on an empty stack breaks the function's contract, and therefore has Undefined Behavior.

There is no portable way to *detect* the effect, whatever it turns out to be for your C++ implementation and particular run of the program. But with a given C++ implementation it may be more clearly defined and there you may be able to catch it.